# AlchemyData News History Longer than 60 days?

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

I'm using the [AlchemyData News](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/newsapi) Demo, and in the demo I can choose dates between today and three months ago,

Do we have in the full version the ability to Search articles older than three months? If not, is there a way to load articles that I choose and use AlchemyData News ?

Answer (score 0):

AlchemyData News was deprecated in favor of the new [Discovery service](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/index.html). With Discovery, you can use the `news` dataset as with AlchemyData News and you can also ingest your own documents.

If you want to learn more about the service, take a look at the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/). It describes the different endpoints and has some code snippets based on the Watson SDKs.

You can also play with the [Discovery demo](https://discovery-news-demo.mybluemix.net/), it will give you information about a company based on the `news` dataset.

And finally, take a look at the [migration guide](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/discovery/migrate-adn.html) if you want to transition from AlchemyData News to the Discovery service.